# Driver Installation for WiFi adapter "Feb Smart Wireless Dual Band N600"

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04, atheros, ath9k

I am having trouble installing the correct drivers for the "Feb Smart Wireless Dual Band N600."  The card worked instantly on Windows 10, but seems it can't find a driver on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  The [sale page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071NZ6DL9) says that it is compatible with Linux through Ath9k, which I believe should be included by default in the kernel.  However, when I run

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

I get the following output:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:1e:00.0
       logical name: enp30s0
       version: 15
       serial: 4c:cc:6a:fe:d0:9e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:55 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fd404000-fd404fff memory:fd400000-fd403fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:22:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fd300000-fd31ffff memory:fd320000-fd32ffff
```

I believe that "UNCLAIMED" means that there is no driver for the device.  How should I fix this?

```
lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 -A3
```

gives

```
1e:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1462:7a33]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
22:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:abcd] (rev 01)
25:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device [1b21:2142]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:7a33]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Information added

Comment: Please see: https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/168c/abcd Is your card seated firmly in its PCI slot? Is the BIOS reset to defaults? Is the BIOS fully updated?

Comment: It is firmly seated.  I'm not sure how to reset the bios or update it (it hasn't been updated since I got the motherboard about a year ago) would that require me flashing it?  It would seem odd for it to be a bios issue considering it works ok with Windows 10 on the same computer.

Comment: Yes, a BIOS update requires flashing it. Windows is not Linux and vice versa.

Comment: After flashing the BIOS with the most recent version, the problem persists.  Both outputs remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

`/etc/modprobe.d`

Look for a file named something like

`blacklist-ath_pci.conf`

do

`sudo gvim blacklist-ath-pci.conf`

look for something like

`blacklist Ath9k`

If the above is present, comment out that line, save the file, reboot and the driver should be active.